# How to get date of a weekday from given weekOfYear and year in Swift?

Tags: swift, date

I have a year and weekOfYear, and I need to get the date of Thursday in that week.

What I have so far:

```swift
let year = 2024
let weekOfYear = 3

var components = DateComponents()
components.year = year
components.weekOfYear = weekOfYear
// How to pass in Thursday if I don't know its date?

let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
print(date?.formatted(date: .numeric, time: .omitted)) // I'd like to get "18/1/2024"
```

TIA for any guidance!

Comment: You can specify the weekday 'components.weekday = 5', as 5 corresponds to Thursday

Comment: @devPau Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that dealing with `weekOfYear` you have to specify `yearForWeekOfYear` rather than just `year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the weekday `components.weekday = 5`, as it corresponds to Thursday.

Note: Sunday is 1 and Saturday is 7; that got me the first time!

Edit: As suggested by @vadian, when dealing with `weekOfYear` you also have to specify `yearForWeekOfYear` rather than just `year` to prevent unexpected results.

Comment: You should also add that when you use `weekOfYear` you also have to specify `yearForWeekOfYear` as pointed out by @vadian. People reading your answer may miss that detail, and the results of using year and weekOfYear are confusing and unexpected.